# Upload com AJAX, nao vai com arquivos com mais de 2 megas

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, post, file-upload

Tenho um código de UPLOAD de imagens com AJAX:

```
$.ajax({url:"php/upload.php", type:"POST", data:new FormData(this), contentType:false,cache:true,processData:false,success: function(resposta){
```

Ele só funciona com imagens de até 2 megas, mais que isso ele não funciona. E essa limitação não é do PHP (fiz vários testes), é do POST mesmo, alguém sabe o que pode ser? Nunca vi isso....

Comment: Onde vai gravar o seu servidor IIS? ou hospedagem? dependente o servidor tem permissão o espaço.

Comment: To testando localmente ainda.... com Xampp...

Comment: Entendi, também uso xampp para trabalhar php e depois hospedo no ar, encontrei o meu configuração está 2mb esta igual seu, veja http://prntscr.com/bls67n e procure `php.ini` e `upload_max_filesize` ... flw

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver seu problema?